# How to Object.freeze wp_localize_script

Tags: ajax, javascript, wp-localize-script

I have a localize script that have sensitive information that i dont want other users change it from the console.
is it possible to Object freeze my localized script?

```
        wp_localize_script('test-script', 'test_ajax', array(
            'ajax_url' => admin_url('admin-ajax.php'),
            'nonce' => wp_create_nonce('test-nonce'),
            'action_thanks' => ACTION_THANKS,
            'univ_short_name' => UNIV_SHORT_NAME,
            'action_general' => ACTION_GENERAL,
            'action_catalog' => ACTION_CATALOG,
            'action_ebook' => ACTION_EBOOK,
            'university_id' => UNIVERSITY_ID,
            // in js needs to be converted to bool
            'is_sf' => IS_SF
        ));
```

Comment: You would just add `Object.freeze( text_ajax );` to the beginning of your script. However, this raises a lot of red flags for me. What would be the consequences if the user could change the values? If you can change values and it causes different behaviour on the server, then its your server code that's insecure.

Comment: is it possible to freeze the localized script from the wp_localize_script function?

Comment: No, it is not possible.

Comment: ok thank you for the quick response!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, it is not possible to do this from `wp_localize_script()`.

You would need to add add `Object.freeze( text_ajax );` to the beginning of your script.